# Counting values in multidimensional array to new array

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [declaration_value] => 1
        [date] => 2018-07-16
        [client_id] => 3
        [declaration_id] => 12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [declaration_value] => 3
        [date] => 2018-07-16
        [client_id] => 3
        [declaration_id] => 12
    )

)
```

how can i make to get the following array result: (count declaration_value if the same date/client_id/declaration_id )

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [declaration_value] => 4
        [date] => 2018-07-16
        [client_id] => 3
        [declaration_id] => 12
    )
)
```

Comment: have a look up this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320014/

Comment: The idea here at SO is that you write the code! If it does not work as you hoped, you ask for help and we try and help you fix it. **But but we dont write code for you**

Comment: Basically in almost all cases if your question does not have some code in it attempting to code a solution, it is off topic

Comment: Can you show the code that creates that array? Ideally you would correct that code so that it creates the array you want instead of creating something you don't want and then fixing it.

Comment: @marmeladze that is very usefull, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$listdb = [
        ["declaration_value" => 1, "date" => "2018-07-16", "client_id" => 3, "declaration_id" => 12],
        ["declaration_value" => 2, "date" => "2018-07-16", "client_id" => 2, "declaration_id" => 12],
        ["declaration_value" => 2, "date" => "2018-07-16", "client_id" => 2, "declaration_id" => 12],
        ["declaration_value" => 8, "date" => "2018-07-17", "client_id" => 2, "declaration_id" => 12],
        ["declaration_value" => 3, "date" => "2018-07-16", "client_id" => 3, "declaration_id" => 12],
    ];

    $sameKeys = ["date", "client_id", "declaration_id"];
    $sumKeys = ["declaration_value"];
    print_r(sum_my($listdb, $sameKeys, $sumKeys));

function sum_my(array $listdb = [], array $sameKeys = [], array $sumKeys = []): array {
    $newdb = [];
    if (empty($listdb) === true || empty($sameKeys) === true || empty($sumKeys) === true) {
        return $newdb;
    }

    foreach ($listdb as $value) {
        $ckKey = "";
        foreach ($sameKeys as $sameKey) {
            $ckKey .= $value[$sameKey];
        }
        if (isset($newdb[$ckKey])) {
            foreach ($sumKeys as $sumKey) {
                $newdb[$ckKey][$sumKey] += $value[$sumKey];
            }
        } else {
            $newdb[$ckKey] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $newdb;
}
```

Thank you for your tips, I solved it.